# Do I need to reset DB every time when I push to heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, git, postgresql, heroku

When I push my local database to heroku postgresql, my current way is to 
    heroku pg:reset, 
then using 
    heroku pg:push local_db remote_db.

Is there any efficient way to do this rather than wiping my entire heroku database content and write new content every time?

Comment: Why would you repeatedly want to push your database to Heroku?

Answer (score 3):

- Don't create anything other than test content locally
- Any settings / configuration / static content, store this in code

In all my years developing, whether it be with Heroku or not I have never seen a reason to push to the database from dev to production more than once.

Comment: What about the scenario when you want to add a new table to an existing prod env? Surely that is relatively common.

Comment: @SimonCooper - Write a migration.

Comment: @timmilwood I was struggling with this myself at the time, and what I didn't realise then was the action of `heroku db:migrate`.  I hadn't picked up on the fact that command would run the migration on my production db.